# Link aggregation and status of network interfaces in "ipadm" command

Tags: solaris, ioctl

I am again rephrasing the issue that we are facing:

We are creating link aggregations [dlmp groups] with two interfaces named net0 & net5:

```
   # dladm create-aggr -m dlmp -l net0 -l net5 -l net2 aggr1
```

Setting prob targets for aggr1:

```
   # dladm set-linkprop -p probe-ip=+ aggr1
```

Setting failure detection time:

```
   #  dladm set-linkprop -p probe-fdt=15 aggr1
```

After this we are adding IP to this aggregation as follows:

```
   # ipadm create-ip aggr1
```

Assigns an IP to this:

```
   # ipadm create-addr -T static -a x.x.x.x/y aggr1/addr
```

Then we check the status using dladm and ipadm everything seems up and running.

Then we tested a scenario where we are dettached cables from above n/w interfaces, but what we got is as follows:

```
   # dladm show-aggr -x

      LINK       PORT       SPEED DUPLEX   STATE     ADDRESS            PORTSTATE

      traf0      --         100Mb unknown   up       0:10:e0:5b:69:1    --
                 net0       100Mb unknown   down     0:10:e0:5b:69:1    attached
                 net5       100Mb unknown   down     a0:36:9f:45:de:9d  attached
```

First issues is that we are getting the state of link "traf0" as **up** in above command output, secondly in the output of "ipadm":

```
  traf0             ip         ok           --         --
     traf0/addr     static     ok           --         7.8.0.199/16
```

We are getting the status of traf0 as **ok**.

So here I have a query, can't we have any configuration where we could get right status of traf0 both in dladm and ipadm output?

[One more thing to add here is, when we don't assign any IP to this traf0 aggregation then in that case on dettaching the cables we get right output in dladm command.]

Apart from this configuration, we are using these aggregations as vnics in zones. There also we are getting the status of these links up in ipadm command output [after dettaching the cables].

A small update::
We have set the value of "TRACK_INTERFACES_ONLY_WITH_GROUPS" parameter in /etc/default/mpathd as no and getting the state of "traf0" in ipadm command as failed, but still we get traf0/addr as ok.

```
  traf0             ip         failed       --         --
     traf0/addr     static     ok           --         7.8.0.199/16
```

Comment: How are you checking link status?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have rephrased the question for better understanding, can you please have a look?

Comment: This page shows a `route add ...` command:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E37516/gnmus.html  What's the output from `dladm show-linkprop -p probe-ip,probe-fdt traf0`?

Comment: @andrewhenle I have already referred this page for transitive probing and had the same output as mention in the page. But on removing both network cable there is no output from the command (you mentioned) and in output of 'dladm' state of traf0 and all the vnics created on this aggregation are in the up state.